# How Do I Determine Whether to Use '->' versus '.'

Tags: c++, windows, direct2d

I'm following a D2D sample and therein, this code came up:

```
    if(!(D2D1_WINDOW_STATE_OCCLUDED & m_renderTarget->CheckWindowState()))
    {
        m_renderTarget->BeginDraw();

        Draw();

        if(m_renderTarget->EndDraw() == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
        {
            m_renderTarget.Reset();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

I noticed that the m_renderTarget used both the -> (I forget what it's called) and later uses the dot operator. For some reason I thought that use could only use one or the other depending of if it was a reference type or value type. 
Apparently I thought wrong but can't find any information about when to use each operator (or more to the point, the purpose of each operator.)

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks really strange. What's the type of m_renderTarget?

Comment: @AxelGneiting it's far from strange, actually it's very common just look at any smart pointer. ;)

Comment: I know what a smart pointer is. It just looked like "Reset()" was some API call on the render target, but it's actually a call on the smart pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought that use could only use one or the other depending of if it was a reference type or value type

Usually, yes.

The fact that both are used on the same object in your code indicates it is a "smart pointer" i.e. an object type which has an overloaded `operator->` that allows it to act like a pointer.

```
    m_renderTarget->BeginDraw();
```

This uses the `operator->` to access a member of the object it points to. `BeginDraw` is a member function of the pointed-to object, not of `m_renderTarget`.

```
    m_renderTarget.Reset();
```

This accesses a member of `m_renderTarget` itself, not the object it points to.  Typically a `reset()` member replaces the pointed-to object with a null pointer.

So in the first case the `->` syntax does something with the object it points to, and in the second case the `.` syntax does something to the object itself.

Comment: Ah yes... it finally clicked in my brain what was going on. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

What the arrow operator does is deference a pointer(pointing towards an object) and then use the ‘ . ‘ operator on the leftover expression.

Its same as

```
    (*m_renderTarget).BeginDraw();
```

Arrow operator is used to avoid confusion with this

```
    *(m_renderTarget.BeginDraw());
```

which of course could be disastrous and could cause program crashes.

This explained with a good example [here](http://codingmash.com/c/the-arrow-operator-in-c/)

Comment: This doesn't explain why both `operator.` and `operator->` are used on the same object (without using `operator*`)